# BarTender Error: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, regedit

[image]

I selected the BarTender from Com tab on preferences screen and add BarTender into my project.

[image]

[image]

when I execute the project with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> on my local computer  I can  print the barcode  smoothly.

[image]

But when I publish my project under wwwroot  I get an error as follows,

[image]

Also I set the project platform “ x86 – x64 Any Cpu” but nothing was changed.

PS: I am giving the screenshots as links because of I have not enough points. Sorry for this

Comment: Did my answer help you fix this in the end? or was it something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an EXE server, so it looks like you need to give Local Launch and Local Activation permissions to the COM Class for the identity that your web site is running under. You can do this with DCOMCnfg.exe. Have a look at the Application Pool identity and make sure it has the appropriate rights. A good way to test the problem is to set it to "EVERYONE". If that works then it's definately your problem, but DO NOT leave it set to "EVERYONE". Once you've proven this is the issue, you'll need to set the activation, launch and probably access permissions correctly.

Comment: For me, it's the "Bartender Format" entry under DCOM Config

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the security settings on the library itself. I had the same issues with Excel & Illustrator COM's.

Even though this is Excel, [this site will guide you](http://www.cnblogs.com/pfs1314/archive/2011/12/02/2272470.html) through setting the security and permissions.

**UPDATE:**

If you can't find the library then it may be a 32 bit one; these don't always show up in 64 bit console (assuming you're running 64 bit..) - if so, you need to launch the 32 bit DCOMCONFIG. See [bottom of the page here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on how to launch 32 bit version.